# The constructor String, String, int, int, Optional<> is undefined in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 2 and using spring data jpa for the persistance.So,I am trying to initialize the object but I am getting error as:

```
- The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<CartItem,Long> is not applicable for the arguments 
     (CartItem)
    - The constructor CartItem(String, String, int, int, Optional<Book>) is undefined
```

Inside my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/finalCart")
public String finalCart(@RequestBody Finalcart finalCart,HttpServletRequest request) {
         finalCart.getCartItem().forEach(s->{
         Optional<Book> b=bookrepository.findById(Long.valueOf(s.getBookId()).longValue());
         cartItemRepo.save(new CartItem(s.getName(),s.getImageUrl(),s.getUnitPrice(),s.getQuantity(), b));
     });
     
        }
```

I have declared here as Optional but I am not able to pass the book object `b` in the constructor of class `CartItem`. My `CartItem` class is:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_cart_item")
public class CartItem {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;
private String imageUrl;
private int unitPrice;
private int quantity;

@Transient
private String bookId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
private Book book;

public CartItem(String name, String imageUrl, int unitPrice, int quantity,Book b) {
    
    //i cannot initialize this.book=b here.
    this.name = name;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.book=b;
}

public CartItem() {
    
}
//all gettters and setters then
}
```

How can I handle the object of Optional<> ?

CartItemRepository.java is:

```
import in.ashwin.onlinebookstore.entity.CartItem;

public interface CartItemRepository  extends JpaRepository<CartItem, Long>{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unwrap value from Optional

```java
finalCart.getCartItem().forEach(s->{
    Optional<Book> b = bookrepository.findById(Long.valueOf(s.getBookId()).longValue());
    if (b.isPresent()) {
        cartItemRepo.save(new CartItem(s.getName(),s.getImageUrl(),s.getUnitPrice(),s.getQuantity(), b.get()));
    }
});
```